# Cannot Redirect on express 4

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, passport.js

i'm new on express 4, i'm trying to authenticate a user with passport-local

```
var UserModel = require('../models/Userinfo').Userinfo;
var Security = require('security');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/signin'
    , Security.passport.authenticate('local'
        , {successRedirect: '/'
           , failureRedirect: './tryagain'
           , failureFlash: true 
         }
      )
    , function (req, res) {
        res.render('./error');
}
```

but, when the failureRedirect is no redirecting, i've disabled the etag on express

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require the [passport](http://passportjs.org/) module.

Also, I'm not sure that the route paths should have the . at the start. So ./tryagain would be /tryagain